# I am trying to run the code for object detection this error is coming

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am trying to detect RRR actor Jr.NTR, while training I am getting this error :
I tried checking hist to check which part of the data is not working but to me every things looks fine please some one diagnose my code

```
Epoch 1/40
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-51-df179639e952> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 hist = model.fit(train,epochs=40,validation_data=val, callbacks=[callbacks])

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     50   try:
     51     ctx.ensure_initialized()
---> 52     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
     53                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     54   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:

InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:

Detected at node 'strided_slice_1' defined at (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
      return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
    File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
      exec(code, run_globals)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 16, in <module>
      app.launch_new_instance()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 992, in launch_instance
      app.start()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 619, in start
      self.io_loop.start()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tornado/platform/asyncio.py", line 195, in start
      self.asyncio_loop.run_forever()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 603, in run_forever
      self._run_once()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1909, in _run_once
      handle._run()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/events.py", line 80, in _run
      self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 685, in <lambda>
      lambda f: self._run_callback(functools.partial(callback, future))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 738, in _run_callback
      ret = callback()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 825, in inner
      self.ctx_run(self.run)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 786, in run
      yielded = self.gen.send(value)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 361, in process_one
      yield gen.maybe_future(dispatch(*args))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 234, in wrapper
      yielded = ctx_run(next, result)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 261, in dispatch_shell
      yield gen.maybe_future(handler(stream, idents, msg))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 234, in wrapper
      yielded = ctx_run(next, result)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 539, in execute_request
      self.do_execute(
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 234, in wrapper
      yielded = ctx_run(next, result)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 302, in do_execute
      res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ipykernel/zmqshell.py", line 539, in run_cell
      return super(ZMQInteractiveShell, self).run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2975, in run_cell
      result = self._run_cell(
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3030, in _run_cell
      return runner(coro)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/IPython/core/async_helpers.py", line 78, in _pseudo_sync_runner
      coro.send(None)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3257, in run_cell_async
      has_raised = await self.run_ast_nodes(code_ast.body, cell_name,
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3473, in run_ast_nodes
      if (await self.run_code(code, result,  async_=asy)):
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3553, in run_code
      exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
    File "<ipython-input-51-df179639e952>", line 1, in <cell line: 1>
      hist = model.fit(train,epochs=40,validation_data=val, callbacks=[callbacks])
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 65, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1685, in fit
      tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1284, in train_function
      return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1268, in step_function
      outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1249, in run_step
      outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "<ipython-input-46-14a3be721cf4>", line 19, in train_step
      batch_lloss = self.lloss(y[1], coords)
    File "<ipython-input-44-38a1384a3354>", line 2, in regression_loss
      true_coord = y_true[1][:,:2]
Node: 'strided_slice_1'
Detected at node 'strided_slice_1' defined at (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
      return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
    File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
      exec(code, run_globals)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 16, in <module>
      app.launch_new_instance()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 992, in launch_instance
      app.start()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 619, in start
      self.io_loop.start()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tornado/platform/asyncio.py", line 195, in start
      self.asyncio_loop.run_forever()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 603, in run_forever
      self._run_once()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1909, in _run_once
      handle._run()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/events.py", line 80, in _run
      self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 685, in <lambda>
      lambda f: self._run_callback(functools.partial(callback, future))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 738, in _run_callback
      ret = callback()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 825, in inner
      self.ctx_run(self.run)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 786, in run
      yielded = self.gen.send(value)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 361, in process_one
      yield gen.maybe_future(dispatch(*args))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 234, in wrapper
      yielded = ctx_run(next, result)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 261, in dispatch_shell
      yield gen.maybe_future(handler(stream, idents, msg))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 234, in wrapper
      yielded = ctx_run(next, result)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 539, in execute_request
      self.do_execute(
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 234, in wrapper
      yielded = ctx_run(next, result)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 302, in do_execute
      res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ipykernel/zmqshell.py", line 539, in run_cell
      return super(ZMQInteractiveShell, self).run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2975, in run_cell
      result = self._run_cell(
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3030, in _run_cell
      return runner(coro)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/IPython/core/async_helpers.py", line 78, in _pseudo_sync_runner
      coro.send(None)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3257, in run_cell_async
      has_raised = await self.run_ast_nodes(code_ast.body, cell_name,
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3473, in run_ast_nodes
      if (await self.run_code(code, result,  async_=asy)):
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3553, in run_code
      exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
    File "<ipython-input-51-df179639e952>", line 1, in <cell line: 1>
      hist = model.fit(train,epochs=40,validation_data=val, callbacks=[callbacks])
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 65, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1685, in fit
      tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1284, in train_function
      return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1268, in step_function
      outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1249, in run_step
      outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "<ipython-input-46-14a3be721cf4>", line 19, in train_step
      batch_lloss = self.lloss(y[1], coords)
    File "<ipython-input-44-38a1384a3354>", line 2, in regression_loss
      true_coord = y_true[1][:,:2]
Node: 'strided_slice_1'
2 root error(s) found.
  (0) INVALID_ARGUMENT:  Index out of range using input dim 1; input has only 1 dims
     [[{{node strided_slice_1}}]]
     [[binary_crossentropy/cond/pivot_f/_3/_17]]
  (1) INVALID_ARGUMENT:  Index out of range using input dim 1; input has only 1 dims
     [[{{node strided_slice_1}}]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored. [Op:__inference_train_function_13093]
```

here is my code:

```
!pip install albumentations
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import albumentations as aug
import os
import cv2
import json
```

## importing roboflow for dataset

```
!pip install roboflow
from roboflow import Roboflow
from tensorflow import keras
from keras.layers import Conv2D, Dense, GlobalMaxPooling2D, Input, MaxPooling2D
from keras.models import Model
from keras.applications import VGG16
```

```
rf = Roboflow(api_key="8OAIvpA0eeCXebsfWJ4U")
project = rf.workspace("malla-raraju-umx2i").project("celebrity-z8hhd")
dataset = project.version(2).download("coco")
augmentor = aug.Compose([aug.RandomCrop(width = 120, height = 120),
                         aug.HorizontalFlip(p=0.5),
                         aug.RandomBrightnessContrast(p=0.2),
                         aug.RandomGamma(p=0.2),
                         aug.VerticalFlip(p=0.5),
                         aug.RGBShift(p=0.2)],
                        bbox_params=aug.BboxParams(format='coco',
                                                    label_fields=['class_labels']))
```

```
with open('/content/Celebrity-2/train/_annotations.coco.json') as f:
  annot = json.load(f)
```

```
coords = annot['annotations'][1]['bbox']
img = cv2.imread(os.path.join('/content/Celebrity-2/train',annot['images'][1]['file_name']))
class_label = annot['categories'][1]['name']
```

`sample_aug = augmentor(image=img, bboxes=[coords], class_labels=[class_label])`

```
def lets_see(img, min_c, max_c, b_color):
  det = cv2.rectangle(cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB), min_c, max_c, b_color, 1)
  plt.imshow(det, origin ='upper')
lets_see(sample_aug['image'],tuple(np.array(sample_aug['bboxes'][0][0:2]).astype(int)),
         tuple(np.add(sample_aug['bboxes'][0][0:2],sample_aug['bboxes'][0][2:]).astype(int)),
         (255, 0, 0))
```

`sample_aug['class_labels']` 
`annot['categories']`

```
os.remove('/content/Celebrity-2/README.dataset.txt')
os.remove('/content/Celebrity-2/README.roboflow.txt')
aug_dir = '/content/aug_data'
os.mkdir(aug_dir)
```

## DataAugmentation pipeline

## It might run but need to make few changes check aug_data folder for sure

```
data_dir = '/content/Celebrity-2'
sub_dir = ['test', 'train', 'valid', None]
try:
  for sub in sub_dir:
    if sub!=None:
      anot_f=os.path.join(data_dir,sub,'_annotations.coco.json')
      with open(anot_f) as f:
        f = json.load(f)
        for indx,image in enumerate(f['images']):
          img_path = image['file_name']
          coords = f['annotations'][indx]['bbox']
          label = f['annotations'][indx]['category_id']
          for _ in range(60):
            img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(data_dir,sub,img_path))
            aug_img = augmentor(image=img, bboxes=[coords], class_labels=['Jr.NTR'])

            annotation = {}
            annotation['image'] = img_path
            if len(aug_img['bboxes'])>0:
              annotation['bbox'] = aug_img['bboxes'][0]
            else:
              annotation['bbox'] = [0, 0, 0, 0]
            annotation['class'] = 1 if len(aug_img['class_labels'])>0 else 0

            if not os.path.exists(os.path.join(aug_dir,sub)):
              os.mkdir(os.path.join(os.path.join(aug_dir,sub)))

            if not os.path.exists(os.path.join(aug_dir,sub,'label')):
              os.mkdir(os.path.join(aug_dir,sub,'label'))
              with open(os.path.join(aug_dir,sub,'label',f'{img_path.split(".")[0]}.{_}.json'), 'w') as o:
                json.dump(annotation, o)
            else:
              with open(os.path.join(aug_dir,sub,'label',f'{img_path.split(".")[0]}.{_}.json'), 'w') as o:
                json.dump(annotation, o)

            if not os.path.exists(os.path.join(aug_dir,sub,'image')):
              os.mkdir(os.path.join(aug_dir,sub,'image'))
              cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(aug_dir,sub,'image',f'{img_path.split(".")[0]}.{_}.jpg'),
                          aug_img['image'])
            else:
              cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(aug_dir,sub,'image',f'{img_path.split(".")[0]}.{_}.jpg'),
                          aug_img['image'])
except Exception as e:
  print(e)
```

## map labels into the data pipeline

```
def load_labels(label_path):
  with open(label_path.numpy(), 'r', encoding = 'utf-8') as f:
    label = json.load(f)
  return [label['class'], label['bbox']]

def load_images(image_path):
  byte_img = tf.io.read_file(image_path)
  img = tf.io.decode_jpeg(byte_img)
  return img

def label_pl(label):
  label_line = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(label, shuffle=False)
  label_line = label_line.map(lambda x: tf.py_function(load_labels, [x], [tf.uint8, tf.float32]))
  return label_line

def image_pl(img):
  img_line = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(img, shuffle=False)
  img_line = img_line.map(load_images)
  img_line = img_line.map(lambda x: tf.image.resize(x, (120, 120)))
  img_line = img_line.map(lambda x: x/255)
  return img_line

def data_pl(data):
  data_pl =   tf.data.Dataset.zip(data)
  data_pl =   data_pl.shuffle(int(len(data[0])*1.35))
  data_pl =   data_pl.batch(16)
  data_pl =   data_pl.prefetch(4) # eliminates bottle-necks in data pipeline
  return data_pl
```

```
data = [None]*3
img = [None]*3
lbl = [None]*3

i=0
for _ in  os.listdir(aug_dir):
  pl_img = image_pl(os.path.join(aug_dir,_,'image','*.jpg'))
  pl_labels = label_pl(os.path.join(aug_dir,_,'label','*.json'))
  img[i] = pl_img
  lbl[i] = pl_labels
  data[i] = data_pl((pl_img,pl_labels))
  i+=1
```

```
batch = data[0].as_numpy_iterator()
batch.next()[1] # every thing's worki'n fine
```

```
len(data[0]), len(data[1]), len(data[2])
len(img[0]), len(lbl[0]), len(img[1]), len(lbl[1]), len(img[2]), len(lbl[2])
```

```
batch_label = lbl[1].as_numpy_iterator()
batch_label.next()
```

```
batch = data[1].as_numpy_iterator()
batch.next()[1] # every thing's worki'n fine
```

`vgg16 = VGG16(include_top=False)` 
`vgg16.summary()` 
`keras.utils.plot_model(vgg16, show_shapes=True, show_layer_activations=True)`

```
def build_model():
  input = Input(shape=(120,120,3))

  vgg16 = VGG16(include_top=False)(input)

  features = GlobalMaxPooling2D(name = 'feature_map')(vgg16)

  classify_head = Dense(2048, activation='relu', name = 'classification_dense')(features)
  classify_head = Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid', name = 'classifying_head')(classify_head)

  regress_head = Dense(2048, activation='relu', name = 'regression_dense')(features)
  regress_head = Dense(4, activation = 'relu', name = 'regression_head')(regress_head)

  return Model(inputs = input, outputs = [classify_head,regress_head])
```

`ntr_detector = build_model()` 
`ntr_detector.summary()` 
`keras.utils.plot_model(ntr_detector, show_shapes=True, show_layer_activations=True)`

```
bpe = len(data[1]) # batches per epoch
lr_decay = (1/.75-1)/bpe
```

```
def regression_loss(y_true, y_pred):
  true_coord = y_true[1][:,:2]
  pred_coord = y_pred[1][:2]

  true_w = y_true[1][:,2]
  true_h = y_true[1][:,3]

  pred_w = y_pred[1][2]
  pred_h = y_pred[1][3]

  delta_coord = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(true_coord-pred_coord))
  delta_size = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(tf.sqrt(true_w)-tf.sqrt(pred_w))+
                             tf.square(tf.sqrt(true_h)-tf.sqrt(pred_h)))
  return delta_coord+delta_size
```

```
opt = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001, weight_decay = lr_decay)
closs = keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy()
lloss = regression_loss
```

```
class detect_ntr(Model):
  def __init__(self, ntr_detector, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
    self.model = ntr_detector

  def compile(self, opt, closs, lloss, **kwargs):
    super().compile(**kwargs)
    self.opt = opt
    self.closs = closs
    self.lloss = lloss

  def train_step(self, batch, **kwargs):
    x,y = batch

    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
      classes, coords = self.model(x, training=True)

      batch_closs = self.closs(y[0], classes)
      batch_lloss = self.lloss(y[1], coords)

      total_loss = batch_lloss + 0.5 * batch_closs

      gradient = tape.gradient(total_loss, self.model.trainable_variables)
    opt.apply_gradients(zip(gradient, self.model.trainable_variables))
    return {'Loss ' : total_loss, 'cLoss ' : batch_closs, 'lLoss ' : batch_lloss}
  def test_step(self, batch, **kwargs):
    x,y = batch

    classes, coords = self.model(x, training=True)

    batch_closs = self.closs(y[0], classes)
    batch_lloss = self.lloss(tf.cast(y[1], tf.float32), coords)

    total_loss = batch_lloss + 0.5 * batch_closs
    return {'val_Loss ' : total_loss, 'val_cLoss ' : batch_closs, 'val_lLoss ' : batch_lloss}

  def call(self, x, **kwargs):
    return self.model(x, **kwargs)
```

`model = detect_ntr(ntr_detector)` 
`model.compile(opt, closs, lloss, metrics=['accuracy'])` 
`test, train, val = data`

```
log_dir = '/content/logs'
callbacks = keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=log_dir)
```

`hist = model.fit(train,epochs=40,validation_data=val, callbacks=[callbacks])`

Comment: I'm not familiar with the libraries, but the error is at `true_coord = y_true[1][:,:2]`, and the error is "Index out of range using input dim 1; input has only 1 dims". Could it be that `y_true` only has one dimension? If so, the way to access it is `y_true[0]`, not `y_true[1]`.

Comment: yeah bro, it's solved but there's another error

Answer (score 0):

I forgot I passed a sliced tensor and trying to slice it again, the error was resolved. Here is the solution

````
def regression_loss(y_true, y_pred):
  true_coord = y_true[:,:2]
  pred_coord = y_pred[:,:2]

  true_w = y_true[:,2]
  true_h = y_true[:,3]

  pred_w = y_pred[:,2]
  pred_h = y_pred[:,3]

  delta_coord = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(true_coord-pred_coord))
  delta_size = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(tf.sqrt(true_w)-tf.sqrt(pred_w))+
                             tf.square(tf.sqrt(true_h)-tf.sqrt(pred_h)))
  return delta_coord+delta_size```
````